# Properties of upper triangular matrix

Tags: general-topology, matrices

let $A$   be the set of all  invertible  upper triangular matrics in $\mathbb{M}_n (\mathbb{R})$  where  $n \ge  2$

then  $A $ is

choose the correct option

$1.$ dense

$2.$Nowheredense

$3.$open

$4.$ closed

My attempt :I take $A  = \begin{bmatrix} 1& n \\0&-1 \end{bmatrix}$

I know that set of all invertible matrix is  dense. You know that  my  given matrix $A$ in invertible and upper triangular,  so $ A$ must  be  open and dense

Therefore the correct option is  option $1)$ and option $3)$

is its true ?

Any hints/solution  will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: why downvote ??

Comment: Note: you used $A$ for the set and the given matrix (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @Damien oksss    ,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\overline A$ is the set of all upper triangular matrices (invertible or not), which is strictly larger than $A$, $A$ is neither closed nor dense. Also, $A$ is not open because $\operatorname{Id}\in A$ and every neighborhood of $\operatorname{Id}$ (and, in fact, of any element of $A$) contains non-triangular matrices. In fact, $A$ is nowhere dense (that is, the second option is the correct one), because the interior of $\overline A$ is empty (every neighborhood of any element of $\overline A$ has non-triangular matrices).

Comment: thanks u sir @Jose carlos